# How to create GitLab rules for approvals

Tags: gitlab

Requirement

- When there is a commit in branch, Pipeline should be stopped and manual approval is required

Please help on how to create it in Yml

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called [Merge Request Approval](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html). You can't set it in yaml, it's done in the repository configuration itself, either using Gitlab UI or API.

In Gitlab UI, go to Project > General > Merge request approvals > Add an approval rule

[image: ApprovalRule]

Same operation using [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#project-level-mr-approvals)

```
curl -Ss -X POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" "$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/approval_rules?name=default&approvals_required=1&user_ids=USER_ID"
```

**Note** : choosing the target branch seems to be only possible for Premium tier.